# How to Get NetworkInterfaceInfo SubType?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am having issues returning the SubType from `Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceSubType`. My main problem is how to call my method which returns the required information. I get an error stating the following

> The type 'Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceInfo'
>   has no constructors defined.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void CallSubType()
{
    NetworkInterfaceInfo n = new NetworkInterfaceInfo(); //Error occurs here
    SubtypeTextBox.Text = GetInterfaceSubTypeString(n));
}

private string GetInterfaceSubTypeString(NetworkInterfaceInfo n)
{
    if (n.InterfaceSubtype.ToString() == "WiFi")
        return "Wireless";
    else if ((n.InterfaceSubtype.ToString() == "Cellular_LTE") | (n.InterfaceSubtype.ToString() == "Cellular_EHRPD"))
        return "4G";
    else
        return AppResources.MainPage_NetworkStatus_Unknown;
}
```

Comment: Are you intentionally using unary or instead of binary? Also, what type is InterfaceSubType?

Comment: I think you should accept some answers for your questions if they were helpful for you.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Here are some good links i've come across from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.networkinterfaceinfo.interfacesubtype(v=vs.105).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.networkinterfacesubtype(v=vs.105).aspx hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the  object, you should use [NetworkInterfaceList.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.networkinterfacelist.current.aspx) Property, you can't create it by yourself as it has internal constructor.

```
var infoList = new NetworkInterfaceList();
NetworkInterfaceInfo n = infoList.Current;
```

Also you can examine whole the NetworkInterfaceInfo's object like this:

```
var infoList = new NetworkInterfaceList();
do
{
     NetworkInterfaceInfo n = infoList.Current;
}
while (infoList.MoveNext());
```

Also, you should change the logical `||` instead of `|`, as @Yuval Itzchakov pointed out.

Comment: Worked excellent. Not sure if you've run across this issue though, where the `Bandwidth` property of `NetworkInterfaceInfo` returns -1? How would you handle this with different interfaces (i.e. Cellular, WiFi, Ethernet)?

Comment: @Matthew Sorry, didn't work with that case. May be it means that the speed of the network isn't stable, and can't be determined.